# Type system for message passing between threads in a DAW implementation

Tags: rust, types

I'm working on my own implementation of a DAW in Rust, and I'm having some trouble with the type system when it comes to message passing between threads. Specifically, I have one thread responsible for receiving messages from the UI and passing them on to the engine, and another thread responsible for running the engine and processing the messages. Thread 1 will send a message and then await for thread 2 to look at it and process it and maybe depending on the message send back the `OutputType`.

For each `BusTrack` created there will be a MailMan and a `MailReceiver`, where the ui could call `send_and_await_recv()` on the `MailMan` in thread 1, and then in each `BusTrack` in thread 2, the `MailReceiver` will check if there are any new messages or otherwise carry on creating and processing audio.

I'm trying to let the Rust compiler infer or check the correct output type for the messages passed between the threads, based on the `BusTrackMessage` enum that I've defined. I've also defined an `OutputType` enum to represent the possible types of values that can be returned by the engine.

Here's a simplified version of the code that I'm currently working with:

```rust
pub enum BusTrackMessage {
    SetMidiTrack((MidiTrack, [type = Empty])),
    AdjustRelease((f64, [type = Empty])),
    GetRelease(((), [type = Value(f64)])),
    AdjustVolume((f64, [type = Empty])),
    GetVolume((Empty, [type = f64])),
}

pub enum OutputType {
    Value(f64),
    Empty,
}

pub struct MessageHolder {
    sender_back: Sender<OutputType>,
    message: BusTrackMessage,
}

impl MessageHolder {
    pub fn new(message: BusTrackMessage, sender_back: Sender<OutputType>) -> MessageHolder {
        MessageHolder {
            sender_back,
            message,
        }
    }
}

pub struct MailMan {
    sender: Sender<MessageHolder>,
}

impl MailMan {
    pub fn new() -> Self {
        let (sender, _receiver) = mpsc::channel();
        MailMan { sender }
    }

    pub fn send_and_await_recv(&self, message: BusTrackMessage) -> <[outputtype based on message?]>
    {
        let (send_back, receiver_back) = mpsc::channel();
        let message_holder = MessageHolder::new(message, send_back);
        self.sender.send(message_holder).unwrap();
        receiver_back.recv().unwrap()
    }
}
```

As you can see, I'm currently using a `Sender` and `Receiver` from `std::mpsc` to pass messages between threads. However, I'm not sure how to define the correct return outputtype and set the type of the channel for the `send_and_await_recv`
function in the `MailMan` struct, based on the `BusTrackMessage` that is passed in.

Is there a way to let the Rust compiler infer or check the correct output type based on the `BusTrackMessage` enum? Or should I use a different approach altogether?

Comment: `GetVolume((Empty, [type = f64]))` etc. isn't valid Rust syntax, what do you mean by it?

Comment: Yes I know and you are correct about std::mpsc , but for the syntax I don't know the correct ones. I mean that the inputtype of GetVolume must be empty and the outputtype of getvolume is guaranteed to be f64